What happens to vtable pointer when upcasting non-pointer object?
I am studying VTable of c++ in university. And maybe I missed something, but I saw following example:
class Parent{
public:
    int x;
    Parent(int _x) : x(_x){}
    virtual void print() const{
        cout << x << '\n';
    }
};
class Derived : public Parent{
public:
    int y;
    Derived(int _x, int _y) : Parent(_x), y(_y){}
    void print() const override{
        cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived *a = new Derived(1, 2);
    Parent *b = a;
    b->print();
}

Here I learned that b's VTable pointer changes to a's VTable pointer, resulting printing "1 2", which seems reasonable.
But I still can't understand why it won't work if I do the same thing with nonpointer:
class Parent{
public:
    int x;
    Parent(int _x) : x(_x){}
    virtual void print() const{
        cout << x << '\n';
    }
};
class Derived : public Parent{
public:
    int y;
    Derived(int _x, int _y) : Parent(_x), y(_y){}
    void print() const override{
        cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived a(1, 2);
    Parent b = a;
    b.print();
}

Why it prints "1", what I actually want to know is what will happen with VTable pointer. Does VTable pointer of b do not change to a's VTable pointer? Why?
Thank you.

Remember that vtable is an implementation detail that is not mandated by the standard (and not something you are supposed to care about). It's a common solution, but not one the compiler is forced to use, it could do something else entirely and still be within specification.

I suspect you have misunderstood something. In the first, neither a nor b have a vtable pointer, since they are pointers. The single Derived instance they both point to (*a and *b) does, and it doesn't change just because you point something else at it. In the second, you have two different objects of different types.

Relevant: Does polymorphism work in C++ without pointers / references?

Parent b = a; is object slicing. b is a Parent, not a Derived

The behavior is defined, and b->print() will call Derived::print(), but there is no guarantee that the vtable even exists as far as the standard is concerned.

With Parent b = a; you will slice (see What is object slicing?) the object a, and loose all of the Derived parts. All that's left is the Parent part.

The VTable pointer is not changing in the first snippet as well. As others have commented you have some misunderstanding.

@molbdnilo Hmmm, as I understand that in first case it works because it points to Derived object, which means it has VTable of Derived. But in the second example why VTable pointer of Parent class, does not get the VTable pointer from Derived class?

So how the VTable pointer actually behaves?

No. Object slicing calls the copy constructor of Parent, which initializes the pointer to point to the VTable of Parent. Once again, in neither of your examples is a VTable pointer "changed (reassigned) to something else". Maybe what you are missing is that the copy constructor would not copy the VTable pointer.

Each class is responsible for correctly setting the vtable pointer according to its class. The Derived constructor first calls Parent::Parent and then overwrites the vtable pointer to Derived's vtable. If you call the Parent copy constructor, it only points to Parent.

@WeijunZhou It might be different question, but does Derived object store 2 VTable pointers? As parent VT pointer and Derived VT pointer? Otherwise I can't understand how Derived object can access to Parent's virtual member function.

Because the derived vtable contains all the same function pointers as the parent vtable does. How else would code use a Derived * passed in as a Parent *? Again, none of this is relevant in your future programming career. Just accept that compiler writers know what they're doing re virtual and that object slicing is a known danger. Forget about vtables, they are an implementation detail and thinking about them helps you nothing.

@dohyunii the vtable for Derived contains slots for all of Parent's virtual functions, plus those defined in Derived. In this case there is only print, required because of  Parent and pointing to the implementation from Derived

What is object slicing?

Another relevant questions: Virtual Table and Object Slicing and When exactly does the virtual table pointer (in C++) gets set for an object?

There is only one VTable pointer, but the VTable it points to includes all virtual functions of Derived, not only those that are declared in Derived, but also inherited ones. See the comment by Caleth. The Derived object contains a Parent subobject, and both objects share the same VTable pointer.

The instantiated object's pointer to a virtual function table is an implementation detail, and is not mandated by the C++ standard.  (Every implementation I've worked with uses that solution.)  Every compiler implementation needs to express the behavior of the C++ abstract machine for well-formed valid programs.  The upshot of that is that the virtual function table and the pointer to that table are not programmatically accessible (within the C++ standard), and any manipulation of it would be implementation specific (and fragile/brittle).

I wonder why nobody dares to write an answer :-)
I summarize it a bit:
The short answer is "Nothing ever happens to vtable pointers".
Every class with virtual methods or derived from a class with virtual methods has its own vtable and every instance of that class gets a pointer to the vtable of its own class.
This vtable pointer inside of the instance will never change.
The key element is that the vtables of Parent and Derived look the same (they point to a print implementation) but a caller does not need to know where the pointer goes to.
In the first example you only have one instance but two typed pointers to the same instance.
The typed pointers don't know the exact type of the target instance, but they know where to find the pointer to the correct print method is inside of the instance vtable.
In the second example you create two instances, it copy-constructs b from the content of a (only the Parent fields).
As the constructed b is a Parent, the instance also gets its own vtable which matches to a Parent.
It might be more clear if you print from both variables and let the print methods output the address of the this pointer
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent{
public:
    int x;
    Parent(int _x) : x(_x){}
    virtual void print() const{
        cout << x << " at " << this << '\n';
    }
};
class Derived : public Parent{
public:
    int y;
    Derived(int _x, int _y) : Parent(_x), y(_y){}
    void print() const override{
        cout << x << ' ' << y << " at " << this << '\n';
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived *pa = new Derived(1, 2);
    Parent *pb = pa;

    Derived a(3, 4);
    Parent b = a;

    pa->print();
    pb->print();
    a.print();
    b.print();
}

Example output:

1 2 at 0xd062b0
1 2 at 0xd062b0
3 4 at 0x7ffd557ea6a0
3 at 0x7ffd557ea690

